# Suma de dos enteros mediante asm inline en C

Tags: c, gcc

Este es mi codigo,lo estoy ejecutando con gcc sobre linux, intento guardar el resultado de 3 + 5 en la variable c, y mostrarlo por pantalla:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int main(){

   double c;

   __asm__  ("movw $0x05,%ax");
   __asm__("movw $0x03,%bx");
   __asm__("add %ax,%bx");
   __asm__("movw %ax,_c");


   printf("%f",c);

   return 0;

  }
```

El error de salida es:
relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `_c' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC

Alguien puede ayudarme?Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero que veo es que estás utilizando un `double` para trabajar, pero no utilizas operaciones de coma flotante para hacer las operaciones, lo que puede causar un error de representación de los valores (A mi entender).

Dependiendo de con qué argumentos estas compilando el programa, puede arrojarte varios errores, yo le he venido dando cabeza a tu problema y he dado con la siguiente solucion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int Valor = 0;

    __asm__("mov $0x05, %%eax\n"
            "mov $0x03, %%ebx\n"
            "add %%eax,  %%ebx\n"
            "mov %%ebx,  %0": "=r" (Valor));
    printf("%d\n", Valor);
    return 0;
}
```

Hasta donde tengo entendido, debe funcionar con el `asm` y `__asm__` por igual, desde la parte `: "=r" (Valor))` creo que es parte de una extensión de GCC y no se si está disponible en el compilador que utilizas. Tu compilador te avisa que compiles con `-fPIC` para generar un ejecutable independiente de posición en memoria con el objetivo de que este funcione aún no estando alineado (según entiendo de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311538/5622844))

Cabe mencionar que el código que he puesto arriba fue compilado para 64-bit, aunque he cambiado los nombres de los registros debe funcionar correctamente al cambiar los nombres de los registros por los de 16 bits, por igual cuando cambies el `__asm__` por `asm`.

- [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494818/copy-content-of-c-variable-into-a-register-gcc)
- Un [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gt0nux) probando el funcionamiento.
- [Especificación de Intel para el inlined Assembly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/694235)

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta , al final consegui hacerlo de una manera diferente que fue pasandole los sumandos tmb como variables desde C:    __asm__("movl %1,%0\n\t add %2,%0":"=r"(c):"r"(a),"r"(b)); siendo a=3 y b=5, pero seguia sin conseguir sumar esos numeros directamente como constante en ensamblador asi que supongo que el problema fue la forma de usar los registros

Comment: Ah! y algo que he visto hoy es que ya no se la misma nomenclatura para las variables de C antes x86 era $_nombre_variable ahora en x64 se hace como lo tienes en tu codigo , aqui la documentacion para quien este interesado : https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/694235

Comment: Agregare ese link a la respuesta para futuras referencias, si te ha ayudado, considera aceptar la respuesta :)

Comment: si me fue de mucha ayuda :) Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Ha sido un placer :), saludos!!!